# XUL + javascript module : TypeError: xxx.yyyy is not a function

Tags: xul, xulrunner, javascript

I'm playing with XUL and modules ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using )

I've defined a small module: under hello01/chrome/content/js/hello.jsm

```
this.EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["Hello", "foo"];

function foo() {
  return "foo";
}

var Hello = {
  name : "bar",
  size : 3,
  incr : function()
    {
    this.size++;
    return this.size;
    },
  open : function()
    {
    return this.incr();
    }
};
```

this module is loaded from  hello01/chrome/content/main.js

```
Components.utils.import("chrome://hello/content/js/hello.jsm");

function jsdump(str) {
  Components.classes['@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1']
            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIConsoleService)
            .logStringMessage(str);
    }

function showMore() {
  document.getElementById("more-text").hidden = false;
  jsdump("Hello!");
  jsdump(Hello.incr());
  jsdump(Hello.open());
}
```

from xul window:

```
(...)
<button label="More >>" oncommand="showMore();"/>
(...)
```

when I click on the button, I see in the jsconsole :

```
Hello !
4
Error: TypeError: Hello.open is not a function
Source File: chrome://hello/content/main.js
Line: 14
```

why does xul know about *Hello.incr* but not about *Hello.open* ?

update: code is available here: https://github.com/lindenb/xul-bootstrap

Comment: can you try to log the value of `Hello.open`, maybe it could help .., if it's not a function it may be something else

Comment: added `jsdump(Hello); for(var i in Hello) jsdump(i);` output: [object Object], name,size,incr

Comment: can you try change a little bit the name of the function, like `opens`. Maybe it does not like the name [open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Method/Open)

Comment: changed the name `open` to `zorg` . got the same error : `TypeError: Hello.zorg is not a function`. Changed `size` to 4 (????.... ) : same error

Comment: maybe you got an invisible char that could stop the declaration of `Hello`, can you declare the function `open` before `incr` (rewriting, not copy-paste)

Comment: $ file ./hello01/chrome/content/js/hello.jsm
    ./hello01/chrome/content/js/hello.jsm: ASCII text
    lindenb@hardyweinberg:~/src/xul-bootstrap$ cat -v  ./hello01/chrome/content/js/hello.jsm
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using
    
    this.EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["Hello", "foo"];
    function foo() {
      return "foo";
    }
    var Hello = {
      name : "bar",
      size : 4,
      incr : function()
       {
       this.size++;
       return this.size;
       },
      zorg : function()
       {
       return this.incr();
       }
    };

Comment: moved (no copy+paste)  'zorg' before 'name': same problem (!!) : TypeError: Hello.zorg is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, got it: XUL-Runner caches some files under `${HOME}/${VENDOR}`
It silently ignored my changes and used the old file in the cache.
See [XULRunner ignores updates on edited files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658585)